# Is it possible to disable XProtectService for a given folder?

Tags: macos, development, anti-virus

I'm using a MacBook for C/C++ development and I'm creating a lot of native executables with clang. While running some of those (mostly those that are on the bigger side - around 500 MB), I can see a bit of a delay when I run them for the first time, and I see XProtectService process use CPU in Activity Monitor. As far as I understand, this is supposed to be some kind of security check; but since I created those executables myself, I'd like to skip it. Is it possible to disable XProtectService for a given folder with binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far disables XprotectService for programs started in the terminal. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65240575/563359.

I'd prefer if there was a way to disable it for particular folders, as the original poster asked, but I found no way to do that so far.